# Unable to select tables/schema in mysql workbench 6.3 (Linux mint 18.3)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, linux-mint, workbench

I am having a weird experience with Mysql Workbench when using it in Linux mint

My workbench version:

[image]

When going to management -> data export (Administration)

[image]

As in snap, the area to select schema and/or chosing tables is narrowed to a level of zero and there is no way to expand.

I was using it in windows and there I never face this problem.

Might be someone else faced this problem in Linux. Guys if you have something, please let me know. I love working with workbench so I don't wanna change the tool.

Thanks in advance

**Update: Fullscreen after hiding panel (as in below comments)**:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried resizing the resolution of your screen to smaller?

Comment: Hey @James Just tried with all resolution available in system display list. NO LUCK, would you suggest something more ?

Comment: how about upgrading to a newer version or downgrade to lower one.

Comment: I am on latest version available for linux mint 18.3, and its been an issue with older version as well

Comment: Or try to hover near the edge/ sides and see whether the cursor changes to resize so that you can drag it to get bigger

Comment: PS: hovering near edges has no option of resize :( But, I was having a taskbar panel  at bottom of the scrren, when I made it hidden then there comes a small area (one line about 10px). Still no way to inlarge.

Comment: Can you share the full screen now?

Comment: @James added full screen image in description. (is there anyway to remove/hide the bottom status area SQL EDITOR CLOSED ??)

Comment: Is your screen resolution less than 1024? coz i have tried 800 * 600 and i came facing the same issue like yours.

Comment: It is 1366 x 768 (16:9) The maximum available

Comment: Or try changing the font size by lowering it.

Comment: Nice trick, lowering font-size is increasing some area, BUT it is not a solution. Le us wait for someone else to jump in or I will raise a concern to community. Thanks for your help James. I really appreciate.

Comment: This is due to UI Issue by MySQL Workbench better it resolves in next version.